# Wait until the other form finish foxpro

Tags: foxpro

how to wait for the other form to close before continuing to execute the code. I need the user to validate some data before processing other information.  here is my code below but after it shows the form it still continues to run the other code

```
USE data\tblcashadvanceexemption ALIAS CA
**promp the user the excemption and user should validate the data
IF RECcount()>0
  thisform.Hide()
  DO FORM frmcaapproval
ENDIF
```

Comment: I presume you have a READ EVENTS somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the second form modal by setting its WindowType property to 1.

Tamar